# Solving for transformation parameters between two 3D point clouds

Tags: matrix, transformation, point-clouds, least-squares, photogrammetry

I have a set of points (x1,y1,z1) and I would like to transform them to another coordinate system which has points (x2,y2,z2). I would like to calculate the scale factor, 3 rotations and 3 translations. I know we have to use absolute orientation and least squares to solve the transformation parameters, however I am not able to get the formulas correctly. And when I tried LSA its not converging properly. I am not sure how to solve for those parameters

I have tried linearizing the basic [a]=s*r[b]+t however this is not converging and the parameters I am getting do not look right

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: I haven't coded it, however I am not able to code the basic affine transformation procedure

Answer (score 0):

This refers to Helmert transformation. In your case, the transformation parameters are unknown, they can be calculated with reference points (for solving 7 params, you need at-least two points and one coordinate of a third point, i.e. 7 equations and 7 unknown params). These params can be estimated from the Jacobian matrix of the transformation function. For estimating those params using a third library, you can use:
[open3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint.html)